# When M2DOC version compatible with capella 1.4.0 will be available?

Tags: m2doc

The 1.4.0 version of Capella is now available.

But the current version of M2DOC is not yet compatible.

Does someone know when the new version of M2DOC will be available ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on it. I will update the [Capella section](https://www.m2doc.org/capella/) as soon as it's released. It should be done this week. I already updated the corresponding [milestone](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/milestone/9) of [M2Doc](https://www.m2doc.org).

Comment: and its done see the [M2Doc Capella page](https://www.m2doc.org/capella/).